# maintaining redirects in nginx from an external source

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am in the situation to give our marketing department the opportunity to maintain their redirects by their own. Until now, they passed the information to the IT department and we maintained it for them in `nginx.conf`.

Some of these guys are quite familiar with redirections in IIS or even in Apache but it is no option to give them direct access to the nginx configuration.

I see, that there is no nginx support for `.htaccess` files which I could give access to and I would also prefer not to grant write access to an conf-file that nginx includes. I expect, that our marketing will break our nginx setup within hours...

Is there a secure possibility without giving them access to the heart of our load balancer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no built in way to properly isolate the rewrite configuration like that. There are three approaches you could take.

#### Map module include

The [map module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) allows you to include mappings from a separate file. Nginx still has to be reloaded after the file is changed, and the mapping file must be syntactically correct, but it does limit what can be done.

`nginx.conf`:

```
map $uri $new {
    include /etc/nginx/marketing.map;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($new) {
        rewrite ^ $new redirect;
    }
    ...
}
```

`marketing.map`:

```
/about  /company/about-us;
~^/people/(?<person>.*)$    /company/people/$person;
```

#### Pre-process configuration

The first is to write a script which transform the redirects from some format which you define into nginx configuration. For example, given a list of space separated redirects:

```
/foo/(.*) /bar/$1
```

and a script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
while read SOURCE DEST; do
    echo "rewrite $SOURCE $DEST permanent;"
done < redirects.txt > redirects.conf
```

to form the following configuration:

```
rewrite /foo/(.*) /bar/$1 permanent;
```

You'd then want to run `nginx -t` on the entire configuration to check that it's valid before reloading.

#### On-the-fly processing

The second option is to use [ngx_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule), [ngx_perl](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpPerlModule) or [ngx_js](https://github.com/kung-fu-tzu/ngx_http_js_module#readme) to implement reading and processing your redirect configuration in nginx itself. For example, the [`rewrite_by_lua`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#rewrite_by_lua) directive allows you to execute [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) code to construct a rewrite. You need to be careful about preformance however since you'll be interpreting code for every request.

Comment: The map module does provided a slightly restricted way to configure redirects.

Comment: The map method looks very promising! So, I will start writing a simple  website to maintain the map-file. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, at this point (2014 fall) the ngx_js project was last touched over two years ago. ngx_lua is very active and well maintained, however.

Comment: Now is available [nginScript](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/nginScript/) (alpha quality) that allows to use a subset of js.