# nginx redirect using map file which may not exist

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up nginx redirects using a technique very similar to the method discussed [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/441235/maintaining-redirects-in-nginx-from-an-external-source).

I also set a default using the following code:

```
map $arg_request_id $url_prefix{
  default /old;
  include /a/b/c/redirect_urls.map;
}
```

The default is a fallback which I want to go to when anything goes wrong. 
The redirect_urls.map file is updated regularly. Now, the issue I have is that there are cases where something goes wrong and the redirect_urls.map file gets deleted (or it's a new machine which does not have a redirect_urls.map file yet). The problem I face is that when I run

```
>>> nginx -s reload 
nginx: [emerg] open() "/a/b/c/d/redirect_urls.map" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:22
```

How can I make it such that if the file does not exist then nginx simply picks up the default value, and simply always set $url_prefix to /old instead of giving a file not found error? Would try_files help in this case?

Comment: Two options to consider: use a wildcard somehow, or alter your processes so this can't happen.

Comment: How would I use a wildcard in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
include /a/b/c/*.map;
```

I don't know if it'd work, but it's all I can think of to try.

Really though, you should fix whatever process that allows the configuration file to not be there.