# Nginx Redirecting from file list

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect

I would like nginx to perform redirects (302) on certain urls while changing part of the url to another based on a file (lets say a csv). For example:

```
https://localhost/foo/100/bar.html to redirect to https://localhost/foo/209/bar.html

https://localhost/foo/102/bar.html to redirect to https://localhost/foo/1000/bar.html
```

https://localhost/foo/99/bar.html doesn't redirect

Because the file(lets say again csv) has the lines:

```
"old";"new"
100; 209
101; 203
102; 1000
...
```

Is it possible without an application server (proxy pass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, not from CSV. You need to list your redirects manually.

```
location https://localhost/foo/100/bar.html {
    return 301 https://localhost/foo/209/bar.html;
}
location https://localhost/foo/102/bar.html {
    return 301 https://localhost/foo/1000/bar.html;
}
```

However you could try the technique suggested in [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/441235/maintaining-redirects-in-nginx-from-an-external-source), using Maps. It's not CSV but it's easier than manual maintenance of redirect rules.

Comment: The maps thing seems it will do the job, thank you for your time.