# How to simplify Nginx Mapping regex rules?

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex, mapping

I don't know if this question is allowed or not. If not, forgive me :)
Anyway, I have a mapping rule for nginx redirection

```
/hotel/xyz/abc  /hotel/xyz/abc-nana;
/hotel/xyz/abc/  /hotel/xyz/abc-nana;
~^/hotel/xyz/abc\?(.*) /hotel/xyz/abc-nana?$1;
```

My question is, can they be combined into 1 rule? I don't know regex well

Comment: What is the exact place where this `map` is used and how exactly?

Comment: I followed this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/441235/maintaining-redirects-in-nginx-from-an-external-source)

Comment: Yes, and do you have examples of URLs for from / to redirects? Do the URLs include query arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `xyz` and `abc` mean any alphanumeric string. Then you are looking for a rule like this:

```
location ~ ^/hotel/([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ {
    rewrite ^ http://$host/hotel/$1/$2-nana$is_args$args permanent;
}
```

`(0-9a-z]+)` matches any alphanumeric string having one or more matches. The results are stored into `$1` and `$2` variables. The last slash match is optional (`?` specifies 0 or 1 matches).

In nginx, one cannot match the query arguments in `location` or `rewrite` statements. However, if you only want to add possible query arguments without modification to the redirect, then `$is_args$args` is enough for that.

Comment: can this be used in a map file / formatting? like this one [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/441235/maintaining-redirects-in-nginx-from-an-external-source)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question and where you were actually using the regular expressions. I'll update the answer once I get more information of the use.