# How to DRY up an nginx configuration file containing a bunch of repeated `rewrite` directives

Tags: nginx

I have an `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with this basic structure:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/html;
    location / {
      rewrite ...;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/html;
    location / {
      rewrite ...;
    }
  }
}
```

There are many `rewrite` directives, all identical between the http and https `server` blocks, so I tried to extract them into an external file:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    include /etc/nginx/redirects.conf;
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    include /etc/nginx/redirects.conf;
  }
}
```

The `redirects.conf` file just contains:

```
server_name example.com;
root /var/html; 
location / {
  rewrite ...;
}
```

`nginx -t -c /etc/nginx.conf` tells me the syntax is fine, but the rewrite rules aren't taking effect. I know the file is being evaluated because if I introduce a syntax error, nginxs barfs. But the rewrites are ignored unless I keep them in the main `nginx.conf` file.

Workaround I will probably use: make use of [the "map" module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) (sample answer showing how this is done [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/441235/maintaining-redirects-in-nginx-from-an-external-source)). Another thing I could use is Ansible to template out the config file, at least making the duplication machine-generated, but I'd still like to know why this is happening to better understand the limitations of the `include` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server blocks are identical (except for the ssl settings), you can just combine them.

> [A single HTTP/HTTPS server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)
>
> It is possible to configure a single server that handles both HTTP and
>   HTTPS requests:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen              80;
>     listen              443 ssl;
>     server_name         www.example.com;
>     ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
>     ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Awesome. Have been serving SSL via nginx for years and didn't know this. Also, for reference, the `map` technique I mentioned above works fine.