# NGINX 301 list of redirects SEO

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have about 250 URLS that need to be redirected from an old site to new.
In the server block I set this statement:

```
include /etc/nginx/301s/somesite.conf;
```

Then in the included file I have a list of the urls (shown are four of them):

```
location = /programs-services/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/ }
location = /meeting-planner/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/speaker-kit/ }
location = /media/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/ }
location = /research-fund/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/about/ }
```

However, Nginx won't restart and complains:

```
unexpected "}" at the end of the first line.
```

Is there a better / correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a better way, although I too would like to, but your configuration is broken due to missing `;` after return directive.

```
location = /programs-services/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/; }
location = /meeting-planner/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/speaker-kit/; }
```

Comment: This answer might also be of interest: https://serverfault.com/a/441517/405852

Comment: Both good answers, but I can get neither to work properly, Nginx complains about Unregistered Authentication Agent

Comment: That is not an nginx error. It appears to be a PolicyKit error.